# Python IndentationError: “expected an indented block” on Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, indentation

I've been getting this error on xcode and vi. Python says the line class LeastModel has an IndentationError: expected an indented block.
I checked my preferences on Xcode to use 4 spaces for a tab and everywhere I've been using tab. Please help me!

```
def make_model(data,model):

class LeastModel():
    """
    linear system solved using linear least squares
    This class serves as an example that fulfills the model interface needed by the ransa function.
    """
    def __init__(self,input_columns,output_columns):
        self.input_columns = input_columns
        self.output_columns = output_columns
        #self.debug = debug
```

Comment: If the problem really is the `class LeastModel` line as you say it is, then the problem must be on an earlier line (is there an `if x:` line right before it, for instance?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have no indented code after the line:

```
def make_model(data,model):
```

You can either:

1. Get rid of that line
2. Write some indented code into the body of that function
3. Indent your entire class definition so that you are defining the class `LeastModel` within the function.

Judging by the fact that you called your function `make_model` and your class `LeastModel`, I think you somehow intended to put the class definition within the function. But this might be a mistake on your part- note that if you define it in a function, you won't be able to use the class outside of the function (unless you return the class itself from the function, with the line `return LeastModel`.

Comment: Ok I just added an indented comment in the body of my function make_model and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there wasn't a copy error and that is what your code actually looks like, you need to indent `__init__()` so that it is inside of the class definition:

```
class LeastModel():
    """
    linear system solved using linear least squares
    This class serves as an example that fulfills the model interface needed by the ransa function.
    """
    def __init__(self,input_columns,output_columns):
        self.input_columns = input_columns
        self.output_columns = output_columns
        #self.debug = debug
```

**edit:** Now that you have included the full code, the issue is actually that you have nothing under your `make_model()` function definition.  If that function is actually supposed to do nothing, add `pass` beneath the `def` line (indented one level).  Otherwise, put some code there or remove the `def` line.

Comment: That's true, but it won't cause an `IndentationError`. (Tested in Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3). The indented docstring serves the same purpose as a `pass`. And besides, the OP says this is what his code looks like anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
class LeastModel():
    """
    linear system solved using linear least squares
    This class serves as an example that fulfills the model interface needed by the ransa function.
    """
    def __init__(self,input_columns,output_columns):
        self.input_columns = input_columns
        self.output_columns = output_columns
        #self.debug = debug
```

Comment: That's true, but it won't cause an `IndentationError`. (Tested in Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3).

Comment: I'm sorry, yes I do have my code like that. I'll change my problem on stackoverflow

Comment: I think it would because there's no indented code or `pass` after `LeastModel():`.

Comment: @dln385: Try it. (The indented docstring serves the same purpose as a `pass`).

Comment: I tried adding pass right below class LeastModel() but I still get the same error